# LIST c# to WCF service not working

Tags: c#, list, wcf

I'm trying to do is just a simple query `toList()` to return to the WCF service but the service is returning an error.

This is all I have ordered from first use to last use:

```
[OperationContract]
List<alertas> LeerAlerta();

 public List<alertas> LeerAlerta()
 {
      return _pr.LeerAlerta();
 }
```

---

```
 public List<alertas> LeerAlerta()
 {

     return _db.LeerAlerta();
 }
```

---

```
  internal List<alertas> LeerAlerta()
  {

       using (var db = new alertas2015())
       {
           var alertas = db.alertas.ToList();

           return alertas;
        }


   }
```

And the object `alertas`:

```
public partial class alertas
{
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int modulos_id { get; set; }
        public string proceso { get; set; }
        public string metodo { get; set; }
        public string descripcion { get; set; }
        public int estado { get; set; }
        public string receptor { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime fecha { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime fecha_aceptada { get; set; }

        public virtual modulos modulos { get; set; }
}
```

The error I'm having is that when reading that wcf service i get ErrorCode 10054 from WcfStorm saying that the host has been closed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message and the method which raises it ? At first look it doesn't seem that theexception is related to the list. normally 10054 means connection reset by peer which is related to the communication and not "parse" / "object" Layer

Comment: I'm debbuging it and VS doesn't give me any error, only 10054 from WCFSTORM. That's all the information I can give. The query returns 2 rows and goes until the last return and there it just stops and 10054 appears.

Comment: What is that "List<alertas> LeerAlerta();"?  Where is the body of the method scoped by curly brackets?

Comment: Add this to config and see what is logged:   `<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name='traceListener' type='System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener' initializeData='D:\trace\Trace.svclog'/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>`

Comment: Trace log returns me: nnerException fue 'No se espera el tipo 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.alertas_7895CEE569AEBE6977614A1873DB1D304F0' con el nombre de contrato de datos 'alertas_7895CEE569AEBE6977614A1873DB1D304F0CEC3F6B5A87E3B3C324BA933840CA:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies'. Intente usar DataContractResolver o agregar tipos no conocidos estáticamente a la lista de tipos conocidos (por ejemplo, usando el atributo KnownTypeAttribute o agregándolos a la lista de tipos conocidos que se pasa a DataContractSerializer)

Comment: I think it has something to do with serialize that list, and i don't know how to do it :(